# Hibernate reverse engineering does not pull DB constraint details

Tags: hibernate-6.x

Any reason or setting needed to pull database Constraint details while doing Hibernate Reverse Engineering ?

Comment: What is "Hibernate Reverse Engineering," and why do you think you need it?

Comment: This will help me to create correct JPA model classes with the constraint details at model level